# Why does array indexing begin at 0 rather than at 1 in languages such as Java and C?

Tags: arrays, data-structures, indexing, performance

Why aren't arrays indexed starting at 1? Why do array indexes begin at 0?

Comment: In coldfusion they start at one, in javascript they start at zero (and in your code (whatever you are using) seems to start at zero). It all depends on the creator's preference. :)

Comment: This is a meaningless question.  Depending on the language you are using, array indexes start at 1 or 0, and in some languages it's adjustable

Comment: Oh ok. Are there any efficiency gain or losses from doing so?

Comment: @Antlersoft It's not meaningless. It's a perfectly good question. :)

Comment: This is rather off-topic for SO.  It might better suit http://programmers.stackexchange.com but [it has already been answered there](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/110804/why-are-zero-based-arrays-the-norm).

Comment: It is an interesting question with a well-defined answer, but off topic for SO.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/110804/why-are-zero-based-arrays-the-norm

Answer (score 2):

Basically it is because of the way the array is actually built in memory.
Your variable points to the start of the array and the "Index" is actually an offset which is syntactic sugar for address arithmetic.

So basically you have the first memory location and you are moving n elements over to get the element you are looking for.

More information here:
http://see.stanford.edu/materials/icsppcs107/07-Arrays-The-Full-Story.pdf

Note this isn't the case with all languages but because of the connection between the index notation and the address addition in most implementations the zero indexing approach is extremely common.

Answer (score 0):

Actually an array var is pointer which points to the base address. suppose int arr[5] is an array allocated in a memory {a,b,c,d,e}

Element-->       MemoryLocation

a  -->          1000

b  -->          1002

c  -->          1004

d  -->          1006

e  -->          1008

here arr acts as pointer and holds address 1000

arr[0] means arr+2*0=1000 (2 indicates size of datatype in this case it is int and int size is 2B)

arr[1] means arr+2*1=1000+2=1002

arr[2] means arr+2*2=1000+2=1004

arr[3] means arr+2*3=1000+2=1006

arr[4] means arr+2*4=1000+2=1008

because of this array indexes starts with zero.